# Jasmine undefined with require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, jasmine

I'm basically following this tutorial: http://kilon.org/blog/2012/08/testing-backbone-requirejs-applications-with-jasmine/
and my SpecRunner.js looks just like this: https://github.com/uzikilon/Todos/blob/master/test/jasmine/SpecRunner.js

My problem is, on line 40, jasmine is undefined! The .js files are loading and being found correctly but for some reason the library is not being linked to my require function. Any ideas as to why? Backbone, underscore, and jquery load just fine. But jasmine does not. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*sigh*
I was using jasmine rc-2.0.0 which uses JasmineRequire. JasmineRequire is a AMD api and will not work (currently) with require.js. I hope this helps someone in the future.